# Conductance from Landauer-Buttiker approach

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, physics

I have a single-rectangular potential barrier in graphene. The transmission $T(E,\theta)$ is given by
$$T(E,\theta) = \left[1+\left(\frac{V}{\hbar v_Fk_x}\right)^2\tan^2\theta\sin^2(k_xD)\right]^{-1}$$
where $k_x=\sqrt{(E-V)^2-E^2\sin^2\theta}/\hbar v_F$. I would like to plot conductance $G(E)$ versus energy $E$, with $E_{min}=-1 \,  \mathrm{eV}, E_{max}=1.5 \, \mathrm{eV}$, using the Landauer-Buttiker approach:
$$G(E)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}T(E,\theta)\cos\theta d\theta.$$
The constants are $V=200\,\mathrm{meV}$, $D=30\,\mathrm{nm}$ and $v_F = 10^8\,\mathrm{cm/s}$. More details about the model can be found in [*Physica E*, 61 (2014) 118](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physe.2014.03.023).

Comment: What are the units of `E`? The units of $k_x$ must also be `meV`, so how does one create a dimensionless quantity from `1 meV * 30 nm`?

Comment: In the original article, the formula contains the Planck constant and the characteristic velocity $v_F=10^8 cm/s$.

Comment: Exactly, I considered $\hbar=v_F=1$ for simplicity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We reconstruct the original formula from [the paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1386947714001106) with dimensional units, as a result, an additional dimensionless coefficient $k$ appears in the formula, and the units of measurement of energy $\mathrm{eV}$ and the length of $\mathrm{nm}$.

```
ℏ = 1.054572*^-27; 
vf = 1*^8;
d0 = 1*^-7;
eV = 1.6021766208*^-12;
k = eV*d0/ℏ/vf;

T[x_, E0_, V_, d_] := ((E0 - V)^2 - E0^2 Sin[x]^2)/((E0 - V)^2 - 
  E0^2 Sin[x]^2 + V^2 Sin[k*d Sqrt[(E0 - V)^2 - E0^2 Sin[x]^2]]^2 Tan[x]^2)

DensityPlot[
 T[x, E0, .2, 30], {E0, -.1, .5}, {x, -π/2 + 10^-2, π/2 - 10^-2}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotRange -> All, 
 FrameLabel -> {"E, eV", "θ"}, PlotLabel -> T]

G[E0_, V_, d_] := 
NIntegrate[Cos[x]*T[x, E0, V, d], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
  Method -> "DoubleExponential", PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
  MinRecursion -> 4]   


lst = Table[{E0, G[E0, .2, 30]}, {E0, -1, 1.5, .001}];

ListLinePlot[lst, AxesLabel -> {"E, eV", "G"}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: This is pretty quick: `With[{V = 1/5, d = 30}, Plot[NIntegrate[Cos[x] T[x, E0, V, d], {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, Method -> "Trapezoidal"], {E0, -1, 3/2}]]`.

Comment: @J. M. Thank you, very good solution of the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, @AlexTrounev, You helped me beyond what I had asked!

Comment: @Alex Nascimento You're welcome. I'm glad that this code turned out to be useful for you.

Answer (score 7):

The following is basically @Alex's answer, but making use of the units framework, and using a style more similar to the question.

First, define:

```
V = .2;
d = 30;
```

Next, determine the conversion factor using Ctrl-= to input the units (I used an image to see how it looks in a notebook):

[image]

*(Alternatively, type in the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) equivalent)*:

```
conv = (Quantity["Electronvolts"]Quantity["Nanometers"])/(Quantity["ReducedPlanckConstant"]Quantity[10^8,"Centimeters"/"Seconds"])
```

> 1.5192675

*(another shorter version that relies on [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity) interpretations)*

```
Quantity["eV"] Quantity["nm"]/(Quantity["ℏ"] Quantity[10^8,"cm/s"])
```

> 1.519267

Then, define `k` and `T`:

```
k[e_, θ_] := Sqrt[(e-V)^2 - e^2 Sin[θ]^2]
T[e_,θ_] := (1 + V^2/k[e,θ]^2 Tan[θ]^2 Sin[k[e,θ] d conv]^2)^-1
```

Next, define `G` but restrict to only numeric arguments:

```
G[e_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[T[e,θ] Cos[θ], {θ, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

Finally, plot:

```
Plot[G[e], {e, -1, 1.5}, AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the great help, but I'd like to know where the unit conversion factor comes in the code.

Comment: @AlexNascimento See update.